# 1.5V to light up LED

Tags: led

Need some help here - I need to light up a normal LED with ONLY 1.5v; yes, 1.5V to light up an LED sounds ridiculous since we need a minimum of about 1.8V or more. But, is there any solution?

Comment: Make a boost converter?

Comment: Joule thief is something I've heard used.

Comment: If human visibility isn't a factor you could use an IR LED. They only require about 1.2V.

Comment: You can buy LED flashlights that run on a single AAA cell, so it's possible.  If you're feeling lazy, you could buy one and pull the circuit board out of it.

Comment: Small portable led light and you need to use AAA battery?

Comment: Most cheap solar garden lights use a 4-pins IC that boosts the single battery cell's voltage.

Answer (score 3):

You need to boost the voltage somehow if you want to emit visible light via a LED.

The obvious choice is a boost converter.  You can find boost chips that are intended to run from a single primary cell, so can work with your 1.5 V.

If you don't need a lot of current, like just a mA or so to light up a indicator, a charge pump might work.  However, at these low voltages the diode drops will be significant.  You might be able to find a charge pump with synchronous rectification.  Or, get clever and use the diode characteristics of the LED to advantage, with the other diode being a Schottky.

Another option is to not use a LED to make the visible light.  LEBs (light emitting bulbs) intended to work from a single 1.5 V battery were commonly available for "pen lights" and the like.  However, the efficiency will be poor, even compared to relatively bad boost converters and charge pumps driving a LED.

Comment: "LEBs" - lol ...

Answer (score 2):

First thing which comes to my mind is a Joulethief like this one.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ZsyU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: white led powered by 1.5]
[source](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/joule-thief-questions-on-the-transformer-inductor.139887/)

Alteranatively you could use a boost-converter like MCP1640.

Comment: Out of interest, could this be called a boost converter? Its the same principle, get some current running in an inductor then cut the ground path and let the free end of the inductor rise to the required voltage. Replace the LED with a cap (and a zener diode) and you have a boost converter no?

Answer (score 2):

I designed a small LED driver using only a few components which can a be found in a junk power supply mostly...

I managed to squeeze about 200ma from this circuit adjusting the values, an alternative to the joule thief..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are some very simple integrated solutions for driving an LED from a single cell.

[Like this CL0117 LED driver.](http://akizukidenshi.com/download/ds/chiplink/CL0117_EN_a.pdf)

The recommended circuit looks like this:

[image]

That's just a single cell, an inductor, the LED, and the CL0117.

You can find them in flashlights.

I couldn't locate a reliable source on the CL0117 (I don't count Alibaba or Ebay as reliable,) but did find a similar IC at Arrow.

[The ZXSC380 is very similar.  Three pin device, inductor, cell and LED are all you need.](https://www.arrow.com/en/reference-designs/typical-application-circuit-for-zxsc380-single-or-multi-cell-led-driver-solution/97ad80920d0d06e1fec4a5fbb27a5683). It is an SMD part, though.   It could be soldered to your LED and inductor "dead bug" style to avoid making a PCB for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might work for you: -

[image]

Or this....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Linear makes an LED driver chip especially for one or two single cell batteries: [LTC3490 Single Cell Minimum Component LED Driver](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3490fa.pdf?domain=www.linear.com)

It is for driving lighting LEDs with between 310 and 385 mA.
1v-3.2v input, 2.8v-4v out.
Can be Dimmed with PWM.
Low battery detect.

Very simple circuit with good efficiency, over 75% @ 1.5v.

---

[image]